# SQL statement giving no result

Tags: sql

Hy, Im having trouble with sql, oracle..

```
SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA  FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE 
DATUM_OSIGURANJA = MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB;
```

My goal is to get only one row with highest value of date (DATUM_OSIGURANJA).
With this code I am getting error 934 which says that group functions is not allowed. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA  FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE 
DATUM_OSIGURANJA = (select MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB;);
```

Comment: And how can I add to search those values using another value? To be prepared statement

Comment: which values post another question with sample data input output

Comment: SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA  FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE 
DATUM_OSIGURANJA = MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB;    
  +   WHERE OIB_OSIGURANIKA = ?;   
OIB_OSIGURANIKA  is from EVP_V_KASKO_ZB

Comment: @ZoranBajcer i didnt get you please post another question!!! but forst give a greennt tick to this question's answer haha

Comment: Hy, Im having trouble with sql, oracle..

    SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA  FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB WHERE 
    DATUM_OSIGURANJA = MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB;
My goal is to get only one row with highest value of date (DATUM_OSIGURANJA). 
How can I add an argument to this statement?
Argument should be OIB from table EVP_V_KASKO_ZB.
something like statement + WHERE OIB = ?;  so I can send this to POSTMAN and there find my values by argument, which is OIB.

Answer (score 1):

Do you look at errors?  Your query is not valid in any database.  Presumably you intend:

```
SELECT MODEL, V_GODINA, DATUM_OSIGURANJA 
FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB
WHERE DATUM_OSIGURANJA = (SELECT MAX(DATUM_OSIGURANJA) FROM EVP_V_KASKO_ZB);
```